# Unable to start spring boot server

Tags: log4j, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and when I try to start my server , I get the following Exception. I understand that this has something to do with dependency conflict, but still unable to figure it out.I am using maven to manage my dependencies.Please help

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the
 classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation
 (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory) Object of class
 [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class
 ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext   at
 org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339)  at
 org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:93)
        at
org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSensibleDefaults(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:62)
        at

 org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:45)
    at

org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:69)
    at

 org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:135)
    at

 org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
    at

 org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
    at

 org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54)
    at

 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:276)
    at

 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at

 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at org.magnum.mobilecloud.video.Application.main(Application.java:30)
```

Resolved:Add the following to the POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you provide your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Hi , Finally resolved this issue by excluding the Logback dependency and explicitly adding the log4j dependency.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. No harm in answering your own question: you should post your solution as an answer and accept it. I've made a improvement to Spring Boot so that it'll identify the source of the competing LoggerFactory implementation and hopefully make the problem easier to diagnose: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/e47435f1b1e83a6e45d2f4e7c02db107f1365f06

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for the sake of future readers: remember that the "mvn dependency:tree" task is your friend here.  It requires some work - for instance you have to recognize that org.slf4j:slf4j-simple conflicts with logback - but when facing this problem (usually because of transitive dependencies) looking at the dependencies in tree form usually sets me on the path to a solution.

Answer (score 13):

Excluding ***logback-classic*** from **spring-boot-starter-web** and **spring-boot-starter-actuator** worked for me

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.1.10.RELEASE") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    exclude module: "logback-classic"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.1.10.RELEASE") {
    exclude module: "logback-classic"
}
```

Comment: I can confirm it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'logback-classic'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my project, it is using

1. spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE
2. both slf4j 1.7.21 and logback 1.1.7. (some dependency , called module A,  depend on logback 1.1.2, this is the issue)

First [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

> Dependency mediation - this determines what version of a dependency will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered. Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition" which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins.
>   "nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies, eg. if dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could explicitly add a dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0

So maven will use logback 1.1.7 in my project.  I am not sure it is my module A not compatible with 1.1.7 or logback 1.1.7 not compatible with slf4j 1.7.21 
Whatever, in my case. I add dependencyManagement in my pom. Tell maven use lockback 1.1.2 only.   Problem solved.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: thank you mate, the other solutions didnt work but explicitly defining did!

Answer (score 3):

the following configuration in my gradle.build file worked for me:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    all*.exclude group: "ch.qos.logback"
    all*.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "log4j-over-slf4j" // allow using log4j 2.x
    all*.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-simple"     // log4j is the configured backend
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Repeat answer but you can use Eclipse to exclude the spring-boot-starter-logging dependency

1. Select dependency hierarchy
2. Search for logging  top right
3. Select spring-boot-starter-logging
4. Right click exclude maven artifact

e.g
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxBBI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Gradle solution is adding below lines in build.gradle :

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try removing any dependency that contains the Logback, the most common one is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot supports Log4j 2 for logging configuration if it is on the classpath. If you use the starters for assembling dependencies, you have to exclude Logback and then include log4j 2 instead.

Comment: Gradle configuration that worked for me is the same that has been mentioned above.

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    all*.exclude group: "ch.qos.logback"
    all*.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "log4j-over-slf4j" // allow using log4j 2.x
    all*.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-simple"     // log4j is the configured backend
}

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding the below dependencies in this order

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -4):

Finally resolved this issue by excluding the Logback dependency and explicitly adding the log4j dependency

Comment: Can you please share the gradle changes ?