# Spring boot with cloudera hive jdbc pom issues

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc, hive

I am using spring boot rest controller and accessing my Hive table using JDBC.

Following is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${cdh.hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${cdh.hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

By using this pom I am unable to start my spring boot app. I get the following

```
SLF4J: Found binding in 

[jar:file:/C:/Users/amoghrao/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/amoghrao/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/amoghrao/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar). If you are using Weblogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLogger(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:277)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at demo.ConfigServiceApplication.main(ConfigServiceApplication.java:10)
```

I used [Stackoverflow post Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061860/unable-to-start-spring-boot-server) to solve the above problem but then i get the following issue

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping.setDefault(Z)V
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(E

mbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at demo.ConfigServiceApplication.main(ConfigServiceApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping.setDefault(Z)V
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addDefaultServlet(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:289)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureWebAppContext(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:236)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
```

I am confused which dependencies to remove to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 16):

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!msg/impala-user/Dy3UyKCwPxI/OHQ-m1JXDAAJ) I resolved this by excluding jetty.

Part of my `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- hive jdbc-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The discussion link is now broken, it says `This group either doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to access it. If you're sure this group exists, contact the Owner of the group and ask them to give you access.`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using @Yu Zhao's answer but with a little change:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
      *<artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>*
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```