# spring-boot, maven: failing to run or package an application

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

i try to package my application with maven and spring-boot but i got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project : An exception occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Invalid source type class [Ljava.lang.String; -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project : An exception occured while running. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while running. null
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup.rethrowUncaughtException(RunMojo.java:387)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithMavenJvm(RunMojo.java:214)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.run(RunMojo.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid source type class [Ljava.lang.String;
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:615)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at PATH_TO_MAIN.Application.main(Application.java:34)
    ... 6 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

here is the command line that i called:

```
mvn3 -e clean spring-boot:run
```

my main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class, args)).run(args);
    }
}
```

and a part of my pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>PATH_TO_MAIN.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And when i run tomcat8 on eclipse, i got this error:

```
ERROR [Catalina-startStop-1] core.ContainerBase: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/project]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/project]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/home/me/workspace-mars/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/project/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar). If you are using Weblogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLogger(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:277)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

Thanks for help.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem reported by Maven can be fixed by changing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class, args)).run(args);
}
```

to this (unnecessary param removed from SpringApplicationBuilder constructor):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)).run(args);
}
```

Regarding the conflicting logging directories please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27566438/821786). Since you are using Maven - and not Gradle - the way you exclude the offending libraries will of course differ, but otherwise it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks. The first solution helps me. The second one, i had  a duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'. I removed it and all work fine. ;-)